# Updating a property binding in another component

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qt6

This is not a working example, my real code is to huge to add to the topic. I just want to understand the concept because I am quite confused. How can I update a property of another component after a signal handler in another component is triggered? I would like to change the value of property `test2` that lives in Page.qml to `true` to activate the opacity to be transparent on the image after the onLetterActivated handler is triggered.

Page.qml

```
    Item {
        id: root
        property bool test2: false
        Image {
            id: headerBackgroundImage
            visible: true
            opacity: root.test2 ? 0 : 1.
        }
    }
```

---

Contactpage.qml

```
    Item {
        id: root

        Page {
            id: page
            visible: true
        }
        
        Subpage {
            id: subpage
            onLetterActivated: {
                page.test2 = true
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Change to `opacity: root.test2 ? 0 : 1.`

Comment: What part of this example isn't working?